# MySQL select all elements in array

Tags: mysql

I have this array:

```
$results = array('1', '3', '123')
```

and this table:

```
id  |  item  |  tag
1      1        1
2      1        3
3      1        123
4      2        1
5      3        1
6      4        3
```

I want to perform a query like this:

```
SELECT item FROM table WHERE ALL 3 TAGS OF THE ARRAY EXIST.
```

In the example I want to return only Item=1, because it's the only Item with all 3 tags of the array.

So far I have this:

```
$query .= " SELECT item FROM #__table WHERE tag IN ('";
$query .= implode("','",$results); 
$query .= "')";
```

But it does not return the correct Items, instead it returns all items that are related at least with one element of the array.

Comment: What does it return? Do you get an error? Or "just" an empty result?

Comment: Do you really wish for them to match simply by them existing, or should your array be logically related to each of the table columns? (item, id, tag)

Comment: @Cassy It just returns all items that have at least one of the elements of the array.

Comment: @hexparrot I am sorry I don't understand your question. I want to return only the items that are related in the table with all 3 tags in the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make the IN work as an AND instead of an OR, you use a HAVING clause to make sure that you get the same number of distinct values returned as exist in the IN clause.

```
SELECT item
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE tag IN ('1', '3', '123')
    GROUP BY item
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag) = 3
```

Comment: What if the count of the elements in the array is dynamic and not always 3? Should it be HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag) = count($results) ?

Comment: @yann: The value you test in the HAVING clause must be equal to the number of elements in the array.

Comment: If there are no duplicate tags for a particular item (in other words, if there is a unique constraint on (item, tag)), then you don't need `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 4):

An `IN` clause is basically just a shortcut for writing out a long `or` chain, e.g.

```
... WHERE a IN (1,2,3)
```

is the same as

```
... WHERE (a = 1) or (a = 2) or (a = 3)
```

If you require that ALL of the values in the `IN` clause be present, you can't use a basic IN clause. There's no `WHERE IN ALL (...)` type construct in MySQL.

You can simulate it with a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT id
    FROM yourtable
    WHERE tag IN (1,3,123)
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING (COUNT(tag) = 3)
);
```

The inner query fetches all IDs where all three tag values are present, then the outer query uses the inner results to fetch the full record.

Comment: Shouldn't the inner query group on `item`, not, `id`?

Answer (score 1):

SQL:

```
SELECT item FROM table WHERE tag IN (1,3,123) GROUP BY item HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag) = 3;
```

PHP:

```
$query = sprintf('SELECT item FROM table WHERE tag IN (%s) GROUP BY item HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag) = %d',
    implode(',', $results),
    count($results));
```